# Optimizing State Machine

Tags: c#, .net

I developed an application which incorporates a state machine. I later found my state machine poorly optimized, ending up taking alot of unnecessery CPU usage. I believe the problem is in the while loops. What is a way i can optimize, is there a go-to way of making state machines in C#?

```
public void Init()
{
    while(isRunning)
    {
        switch(state)
        {
           case STATE.IDLE:
                break;

           case STATE.DO_WORK:

                Object.Work();
                isWaiting = true;
                state = STATE.WAIT_WORK;  
                break;

           case STATE.WAIT_WORK:

                while (isWaiting) 
                {
                    //Wait for isWaiting to become false after work is done
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                } 
                state = STATE.IDLE;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up the State design pattern.

Comment: You'd have to redesign this, possiblity to have an async task. What you have here is you start another thread but you actively wait for it to finish. What's the point of it?

Comment: @WiktorZychla That is correct, that is my mistake, it was just supposed to be a function from an object, not another thread. Edited.

Comment: What if you sleep longer, like 100ms? Does it also consume CPU? Also, maybe it's the `Work` that consumes your CPU, not this state machine?

Comment: The go-to way of creating a state machine in .NET is using an existing package like [`StateLess`](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless) instead of inventing your own.

Comment: Agree with @WiktorZychla : This code is not consuming CPU, but `Object.Work()` probably is. Add logging when a Thread start/stops performing work to determine what is actually using CPU.